# Velvet screen after grub selection

Tags: 11.10, grub2, uefi

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, the boot seems to stop after selecting the ubuntu option (same with the rescue one) in the grub menu.

At first I thought this was related to grub-efi, as I've had similar problems after a Ubuntu 11.04 update which replaced grub-efi with grub-pc and got me stuck on a "elf magic" grub console (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/800910).

While the 11.04 problem was resolved with a simple `chroot` and `apt-get install` from the live cd, that solution doesn't work this time.

The drive with the bootloader is a sata3 ssd with 64 gb gpt (sdb1 20 mb efi boot partition fat16, sdb2 60 gb root ext4 and sdb3 4 gb swap) on a msi e350ia-e45 mainboard with a pair of 2 TB ext4 mbr drives for photos/music/movies.

I've tried a few grub-install/update-grub with boot-directory sdb1 from chroot, but I cant seem to go anywhere.

Even this guide: http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Grub2#EFI (ofc I replaced grub2 with grub in the grub-install and efibootmgr commands) doesnt seem to get me anywhere.

Any help or ideas are appeciated ;)

edit: I guess its the combination of gpt/uefi that also seems to haunt f16

edit: same with 12.04 beta btw

Comment: are you able to boot from a Live CD

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,

Comment: also, this guy posted bout the same routine I've been trying for months now: http://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi still doesnt work for me though

Comment: @blueXrider and yeah, live cds work fine

Answer (score 2):

After another 2 days I finally have a solution.

I switched the SATA controller from AHCI to IDE in my BIOS, which made the system bootable, but I still wasn't happy with that.

So I searched around a bit and figured that the AHCI kernel module wasnt loaded at all, which explains why the live CD and IDE mode worked.

So I added the AHCI module to the `initramfs`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
```

In the text editor, I just added `ahci` at the end of the file. Then I saved the file, closed the text editor, and ran:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Now booting works fine. I guess I'll have to redo that every time there's an kernel update, though.

Comment: You will generally not have to redo this every time you upgrade your kernel to a newer version; this fix should be retained across kernel updates.

Comment: Typically one should use `AHCI` for better performance (at least with SSD's) though it may mean you need to reinstall after changing it.

Comment: oh trust me, I've learned my lesson. nowadays I set all the uefi stuff to legacy and just boot via syslinux to a partitionless btrfs disk - this saves me fiddling around with uefi partitions and uefi boot managers. sadly iirc my first uefi mainboard didnt have any legacy settings (also no secure boot - this was pre-win8) so that wouldnt have worked 4 years ago.